# WPF Xceed PropertyGrid change background

Tags: wpf, background, propertygrid, foreground

I have to define a property grid only in code behind

```
Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid m_PropertyGrid;
```

Then I want to be able to customize it according to the selected object. 
So I define the event

```
private void M_PropertyGrid_SelectedObjectChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    foreach (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyItem item in (sender as Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid).Properties)
    {
        item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        item.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        item.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
    }
}
```

but the effect is the following

[image]

it seems that the effect is only on the first column and not the second one.

what's more I can't change the effect on enums so when a combo opens the effect is unreadable

[image]

thank you for any help